# JS Error: Element is not attached to a Document

Tags: javascript, jquery

Am trying to convert div to image using [html2canvas](https://html2canvas.hertzen.com/) lib , but am keep getting that error

```
html2canvas.min.js:20 Uncaught (in promise) Error: Element is not attached to a Document
at html2canvas.min.js:20
at html2canvas.min.js:20
at Object.next (html2canvas.min.js:20)
at html2canvas.min.js:20
at new Promise (<anonymous>)
at a (html2canvas.min.js:20)
at Vs (html2canvas.min.js:20)
at html2canvas.min.js:20
at HTMLInputElement.<anonymous> (index4.html:18)
at HTMLInputElement.dispatch (jquery-2.2.4.min.js:3)
```

I not understand what's wrong with my code , when i run the code on jsfiddle it not give me any error when i run it on my local system it give me error.

**code**

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.4.min.js" ></script>
<script src="https://html2canvas.hertzen.com/dist/html2canvas.min.js"></script> 
</head>

<body>
<div id="phone">45454565756677</div>    

<div id="out_image"></div>
    
 <input type="button" value="Data to Image" id="data_to_image_btn" >
  
  
  
<script>
    
    $(function() { 
    $("#data_to_image_btn").click(function() { 
        html2canvas($("#phone"), {  // no error with : document.getElementById( but nothing is rendered
            onrendered: function(canvas) {
                console.log('done ... ');
                $("#out_image").append(canvas);
            }
        });
    });
}); 
</script>  
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Try this:

```
html2canvas($("#phone")[0]).then((canvas) => {
    console.log("done ... ");
    $("#out_image").append(canvas);
});
```

The two changes are: pass the first element of the jquery selection to html2canvas, rather than the selection itself. That gets rid of the error ... but for something to happen it seems that you need to treat the call as a Promise, rather than pass an `onrendered` callback (that's the second change)

Comment: thanks i tried with [0] now am not getting error but nothing is rendered it same as when i use document.getElementById()  i not get error but nothing is rendered

Comment: it appears that `onrendered` used to be an option but has since been deprecated in favour of promises. You really have to use `.then` or `await/async`.